# Escape an & (ampersand) at the start of a YAML entry?

Tags: yaml

An ampersand at the start of a YAML entry is normally seen as a label for a set of data that can be referenced later.  How do you escape a legitimate ampersand at the start of a YAML entry.  For example:

---
- news:
    news_text: &ldquo;Text!&rsquo;

I am looking to not have &ldquo be a label within the yaml file, but rather when I get parse the YAML file to have the news_text come back with the &ldquo; in the entry.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just put quotes around the text

```
require 'yaml'

data = <<END
---
- news:
    news_text: "&ldquo;Text!&rsquo;"
END

puts YAML::load(data).inspect

# produces => [{"news"=>{"news_text"=>"&ldquo;Text!&rsquo;"}}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably can enclose the text in quotes:

```
---
- news:
    news_text: "&ldquo;Text!&rsquo;"
```

Besides, you can probably just as well use the proper characters there:

```
---
- news:
    news_text: “Text!’
```

Putting escapes specific to a totally different markup language into a document written in another markup language seems ... odd to me, somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could put the string on the next line, if you put a '**>**' or '**|**' at the spot where the string used to be. Using the '**|**' character your parser will keep your custom line breaks, while '**>**' turns it into one long string, ignoring line breaks.

```
- news:
    news_text: >
        &ldquo;Text!&rsquo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting the entire string in single quotes would do what you want:

```
---
- news:
    news_text: '&ldquo;Text!&rsquo;'
```

But, I think that any yaml library should be smart enough to do that for you?